# Refresh markers on moving map, Leaflet Photo (Leaflet Markercluster)

Tags: leaflet

Some geotagged photos are saved in a Piwigo library, and this page aim is to put them into a Leaflet map only if they fit into the bounding box and are inside a certain category, and display a dropdown menu for the user to change the category. The user moves the map and other photos are loaded, into the new bounding box or window bounds.

An extension to **Markercluster** ([code](https://mappingforyou.eu/javascript/leaflet.markercluster2.js) / [introduction](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster)), called **Leaflet photo** ([code](https://mappingforyou.eu/javascript/Leaflet.Photo2.js) / [introduction](https://github.com/turban/Leaflet.Photo)) is used to display photos in clusters and thumbnails (image)

The process of loading photos through **rewquest** ([code](https://mappingforyou.eu/javascript/rewquest.min.js) / [introduction](https://github.com/ded/reqwest)) (and jquery, [code](https://mappingforyou.eu/javascript/jquery.min.js), if I'm right), calling **imagesinCat.php** ([modified code](https://mappingforyou.eu/gallery/imagesInCat.txt) / [introduction](https://github.com/LeOSW42/PiwigoImagesAndGPX/)), a PHP page that reads through a Mysql database, according to the category and the bounds of the map in the window, works fine

[image: Leaflet Photocluster]

However, when moving/zooming the map (event onMoveEnd), the older photos are not removed, and the add up to the new ones, and so if you move the map ten times, all photos would appear eleven times; I've tried things like `photoLayer2.clear()`, without success;

[image: two, three times the same image]

The page is here: https://mappingforyou.eu/test/ .

Divs in the html, including one that holds the dropdown menu and calls an event:

```
<div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 80vh;"></div>
<div style="width: 100%; height: 4vh;">
    <form method="post" class="stroke-text">
        <label labelfor="aforma" id="aformb">Photos:</label>
        <select size="1" id="photosdropdown" name="photosdropdown" class="stroke-text" id="photosdropdown" onchange="photoTrigger(this)">
            <option value="35">Paysage</option>
            <option value="12">Tout</option>
            <option value="4">Ile de France</option>
        </select>
    </form> 
</div>
<div style="width: 100%; height: 15vh;" id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel">


</div>
```

**javascript :**

```
// map
const map = L.map('map').setView([48.505, 2.09], 11);

const tiles = L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    maxZoom: 18,
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
}).addTo(map);

let catID = 35;

// Photos dropdo



// piwigo

function loadPiwigo() {

    if (map.hasLayer(photoLayer2)) {
        photoLayer2.removeLayers();
    };
    var photoLayer2 = L.photo.cluster({
        spiderfyDistanceMultiplier: 1.2
    }).on('click', function(evt) {
        evt.layer.bindPopup(L.Util.template('<a href="{url}" target="_blank"><img src="{photo}"/></a><p style="margin: 0 !important;">{caption} <span style="display:inline-block; width: 100%; font-size: 0.8em; white-space: nowrap; overflow:hidden !important; text-overflow: ellipsis;">{comment}<br>{caption}</span></p>', evt.layer.photo), {
            className: 'leaflet-popup-photo',
            minWidth: 250
        }).openPopup();
    });


    reqwest({
        url: 'https://mappingforyou.eu/gallery/imagesInCat.php?catID=' + catID + '&minLat=' + map.getBounds().getSouthWest().lat + '&maxLat=' + map.getBounds().getNorthEast().lat + '&minLng=' + map.getBounds().getSouthWest().lng + '&maxLng=' + map.getBounds().getNorthEast().lng,
        type: 'jsonp',
        success: function(data) {
            var photos = [];

            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var photo = data[i];
                if (photo[0]) {
                    photos.push({
                        lat: photo[0],
                        lng: photo[1],
                        url: photo[4],
                        photo: photo[5],
                        caption: photo[2],
                        comment: photo[6],
                        thumbnail: photo[3]
                    });
                }
            }

            photoLayer2.clear();
            photoLayer2.add(photos).addTo(map);
            //  map.fitBounds(photoLayer.getBounds());
        }
    });

};

window.addEventListener('load', loadPiwigo);
map.on('moveend', loadPiwigo);

function photoTrigger() {
    photosdropdown_getready = document.getElementById("photosdropdown");
    console.log("Photoscat:" + photosdropdown_getready.value);
    catID = photosdropdown_getready.value;
    console.log("Transferredcatphoto:" + catID);

    loadPiwigo;
};
```

Comment: Thanks, @TomazicM . This is updated

Comment: @TomazicM looks like I've just solved it. I'll post   the answer in a few minutes